# Call to service in Cloud Foundry via code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I've deployed a service to Cloud Foundry and I was able to access it from the browser (to see the service data). The application is bounded to UAA so, in the browser, I need to enter a user and password.

While doing this, I was able to see the app data. Now, I want to connect to it **via code**. How should I put the user password in this API?

I've  tried the following code. The URL is the one that I put in browser that works.

```
var oParmas = {
        username: "myUser",
        password: "myPass"
    }

$.get(sUrl,oParmas)
    .done(function(results) {
        self._mapResults(results);
    })
```

When I try it like this I get HTTP 500 error.

Comment: I am missing details? What type of authentication are you doing? Is this a specific protocol? Which service? ...

Comment: @data_henrik - 1 . UAA via user password , 2. not sure which protocol ,maybe you can tell me how to check it ? 3 . UAA service

Comment: @JennyHilton Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to do here? Did you provision a service and are wondering how to access it, or are you trying to create your own? Is it an app deployed to Bluemix? What is the "app data" you want to see?